# Canopy Version 1.7.2.3327 Errors when installing extension basemap

Tags: python, installation

Errors when installing extensions.  I have installed Canopy Version: 1.7.2.3327 and then am trying to install extension basemap.  I receive the following error:

```
Warming up...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action_worker.py", line 54, in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action.py", line 193, in execute
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 352, in <lambda>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 889, in _install
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py", line 85, in install_package
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 106, in install_package
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 181, in _execute_in_subprocess
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\enpkg_api.py", line 216, in _propogate_progress_events
IOError: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Pretty much I cannot get any of the extensions installed.  It does have 11 updates that I cannot get installed either.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled and tried again, but still does not work.  I have disabled user active control to Never Notify.  I have posted this same question in the PLTW-Computer Science discussion forum with the hopes that maybe someone else has this same error.

Please advice as I have training in 1 week and need all software installed.

Comment: could you please describe how you do the installation, check if you have network configurations set properly as this error is related to sockets

Comment: As for how I complete the installation, after I sign into Entought Canopy, I click on Package Manager, then I go to Available, then to basemap and click install.  It starts with the warming up.... and then I get the error.  What  network configurations am I missing?  I have made sure I have admin rights and then I set my user active control to Never Notify.